# Get vtable pointer for class without instance

Tags: c++11, gcc, clang

I need to statically capture the vtable pointer for classes, and trying to think of tricks to solve this problem for each major compiler.

The ideal goal is that I could write something like this:

```
void **vtbl = GET_VTABLE(ClassName);
```

I managed to craft an MSVC solution:

```
#define STRINGIFY(Token) #Token
#define MSVC_MANGLE_VTABLE(Class) STRINGIFY(??_7##Class##@@6B@)
#define MSVC_VTABLE(Class) (__pragma(warning(suppress: 4483)) __identifier(MSVC_MANGLE_VTABLE(Class)))
```

Note: it took me quite a while to think of that stringification trick with the awkward MSVC mangled symbol name! ;)

Now I need a GCC solution, and I thought this would be easy, since their symbol names are valid C identifiers. I intended to approach it with a simple extern:

```
extern "C" void **_ZTV9ClassName;
```

Wrap that in a macro, done... except there's a problem; GCC mangled names follow the pattern `#Name`, where # is the number of characters in Name, ie, `4Name`, or `9ClassName` as I wrote above.

This seems to be a real problem... I can't think of any clever way to create a macro that can take a class name and produce that symbol name.

An alternative (and probably preferable) solution would be to find some expression within C++ to coerce GCC/Clang (either one) to emit the pointer in some way. I haven't been able to think of any such expression. Perhaps there is some GCC or Clang extension that can be used to coerce the compiler to emit with the pointer?

If anyone has any ideas to move forward on either approach, or some other creative ideas... I'm all ears!

Note, I'm happy to depend on C++11 features.

Edit: One extra thought, I have managed to fabricate the symbol name as a string with a template, but things like `__attribute__(alias("name"))` expects a literal, the template doesn't seem to work, even though it is resolved at compile time >_<

Comment: Why do you need vtable pointers?

Comment: So I can analyse, modify, duplicate it. Resolve method pointers statically, etc.

Comment: I understand *what* you can do with a vtable. I'm askiing *why* you need any of this.

Comment: I'm effectively jit-ing script language classes derived from C++ classes using C++11 magic and some hacks. It improves performance and also significantly reduces the boilerplate workload in our front-end api to have a class extensible by script.  
In addition to that, I think such a function should also just exist in the toolbox.

Comment: Vtables are internal compiler structures and are subject to change without notice. Implementors understandably don't want to deal with inevitable influx of bug reports due to misuse. Anyway, use case is still not clear. Why user-written C++ code needs to know its vtbl addresses? In the code you generate, you just mangle the symbol directly. Can you show what a C++ user needs to do to export his class to a scripting language?

Comment: And of course simple easy names like _ZTV9ClassName are not enough when namespaces and nested classes and whatnot are present.

Comment: I understand the limitations of the extern approach... if you would like to offer some other creative alternative solutions, I'm very keen to hear them :)